# ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized when I want to create an Angular project in vscode

Tags: node.js, angular, terminal

I am beginner with Angular

when I want to create a new Angular project in vs code, face with this error:

ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- ng new armin-app
- ~~

- I have been installed Node.js completely
- I installed Angular using this command: npm install -g @angular/cli
- I added "C:\Users\username\Appdata\Roaming\npm to environment Variables section in advanced system settings...

Comment: What was the prompt feedback on the npm install? Do you need to set ExecutionPolicy 
 as per https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#install-the-angular-cli ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I was using PowerShell. When you open a terminal in VSCode, the default terminal app is PowerShell. You can switch to the usual Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and may not have problems like that. I hope that helps you.